# Is there data leakage while splitting the data this way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

Is there any chance of data leakage while splitting dataset in this way:

```
def split_dataset(ds, train_ratio=0.8, val_ratio=0.1, test_ratio=0.1, shuffle=True):
    # Get dataset size
    dataset_size = len(ds)

    # Calculate split sizes
    train_size = int(train_ratio * dataset_size)
    val_size = int(val_ratio * dataset_size)
    test_size = dataset_size - train_size - val_size

    # Shuffle dataset if required
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(dataset_size)

    # Split dataset
    train_dataset = ds.take(train_size)
    val_dataset = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    test_dataset = ds.skip(train_size + val_size).take(test_size)

    return train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset
```

Training a deep learning model
Just surprised by the model's accuracy, it's over 98%.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what `ds` is; post a [mre].

Comment: There's far too little info here to judge. You need to think about things like correlations between the data if you're shuffling it, as well as any other statistical relationships that might exist.